# Creating nested objects in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What is the right™ way to design DRF serializers that receive the following POSTed data to a `List` model:

```
{
    list_name: "friends",
    contacts: ["alice", "bob"]
}
```

And handles the creation of the nested `Contact` objects? Additionally, assume an extra step is needed to convert the names to capitalized (`['Alice', 'Bob']`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use django-rest-framework-bulk which is linked from Django Rest Framework's documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/third-party-resources#views

'Implements generic view mixins as well as some common concrete generic views to allow to apply bulk operations via API requests.'

I'm not sure if it's the 'right™' way of doing it but the library is being actively maintained and it's 9 months old and seems to have a few contributors. Worth looking into.